# How to create submenu in html format from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, submenu

```
<div id="menu">    
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>               
    </ul>       

</div>
```

This is menu code and menu items are static and I want to display `product1`, `product2`, `product3` dynamically from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way i think could be using **repeater control** to bind multiple `<li>` tags from server side.

You can use ajax call as well to bind at client if you don't want to post back to refresh the menu item.

Code:

May this will Help to get you the idea of one way of binding it from server side…..

ASPX

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>

            <ul>
                <asp:Repeater ID="_rptSubMenu" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><a href="#"><%Eval(ProductId) %> </a>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>


            </ul>
        </ul>
```

CS

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindMenu();
        }

        public void bindMenu()
        {
            //ADO Code to get menu Items from Database
            //You can load it directly form DataTable or you can create a LIST with Menu Entity as i have


            string connectionstring = "";
            List<MenuItem> lstMenu = new List<MenuItem>();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,MenuName FROM TM_Menu", con);
            SqlDataReader dr;

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                lstMenu.Add(new MenuItem { ProductID = dr["Id"].ToString(), Name = dr["Name"].ToString() });
            }           

            _rptSubMenu.DataSource = lstMenu;
            _rptSubMenu.DataBind();

        }
    }

    public class MenuItem
    {
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.. 
my data base is ms sql so we might be different on the code of retrieving the data on database

```
<div id="menu">    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>

        <?php
            $sqli = "select item  from Rroducts ";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqli );
                if( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                     $item= $row[' item'];
                echo "<li><a href='#'>".$item."</a></li>";
                }
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt2;   
        ?>

        </ul>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

Comment: ah sorry sir, i didn't noticed the tags earlier